# Magento 1: How to prevents Bots which are crawling internal URL's?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

Daily we get in our `webservers` logs hundreds of thousands of lines from bots who are visiting these paths:

```
/catalog/category/view/id/$1

/catalog/product/view/id/$i
```

where i is between 1 to 54000

As immediatelly measures:

1. We redirect these paths to a 404 error using in .htaccess file. As long as we use URL's rewrites nothing is affected inside Magento.
2. We catch the IP's and block them for a week using Fail2Ban.

Please let me know if there are any issues in time using method 1 (we did not re-index the Catalog URL's yet to see what is happening). If there are any other methods you are welcomed to reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
##### Block unwanted Crawler Bots that clog your server #####

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 80legs [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Add this to your htaccess. You can also add following codes

```
##### Search Engine redirects and rewrites for SEO purposes #####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 ##### Redirect away from /index.php and /home  
 ##### Warning: This index.php rewrite will prevent Magento 
 ##### Connect from working. Simply comment out the 
 ##### following two lines of code when using Connect.
 ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://
 redirect 301 /home http://www.yourdomain.com

 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

also ensure that your htaccess has following codes

```
# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
#Disallow: /js/
#Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
#Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

This should help

Comment: Using robots.txt is not efficient at this stage. We have a long list of bots updated regularly. Most of those records in the log are coming from known browsers, they look like normal visitors. Blocking the paths and banning the IP's I think is the best solution for the moment. I was interested knowing if this rewrite of the paths could affect in some ways Magento core.